# How to maven-publish a Gradle project JAR with provided scope

Tags: maven, pom.xml, gradle-2

Given a Gradle web project that is to be published as a JAR (so that it can be a dependency of another Gradle web project, which has a different release cycle).

The `maven-publish` plugin is used:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

The web project has a `providedCompile` dependency:

```
providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
```

A `jar` is published using `mavenJava`:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        // mavenJava publishes a jar file
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

The problem is that `javax.servlet-api` has a `runtime` scope in the resulting Maven POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Runtime scope makes no sense for the servlet-api, it is even harmful. How can the scope be set to `provided` in the pom.xml?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the help of `pom.withXml` (see this Gradle [sample](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/maven-publish/pomCustomization/build.gradle)) it's possible to transform Gradle's `providedCompile` into `provided` scope for Maven's POM:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            // providedCompile -> provided scope
            pom.withXml {
                asNode().dependencies.'*'.findAll() {
                    it.scope.text() == 'runtime'  && project.configurations.providedCompile.allDependencies.find { dep ->
                        dep.name == it.artifactId.text()
                    }
                }.each() {
                    it.scope*.value = 'provided'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

What the `pom.withXml` section does is going through all dependencies of type `providedCompile` within the Gradle project configuration and changing the scope to be written into the Maven `pom.xml` from `runtime` to `provided`.

The generated `pom.xml` now has the `provided` scope set for the `javax.servlet-api`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    [...]
    <dependencies>
        [...]
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Gradle 4.5.1 works a bit differently: it generates POM with the scope of servlet-api set to `compile`. The solution above still works, you just need to match `it.scope.text() == 'compile'` instead.