# How Map gradle 'compileOnly' to 'provided' in generated pom (generatePom...)

Tags: maven, gradle

I am using `gradle 4.3.1` I have dependencies in scope `compileOnly` when I publish to maven I see that these dependencies are not in the pom file.

I would like to map them to `provided` scope of maven.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any clean solution (maven-publish plugin is still incubating), so I took inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25201395/2838501 and have a dirty solution:

```
publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        from components.java

        pom.withXml {
            project.configurations.compileOnly.allDependencies.each { dep ->
                asNode().dependencies[0].appendNode('dependency').with {
                    it.appendNode('groupId', dep.group)
                    it.appendNode('artifactId', dep.name)
                    it.appendNode('version', dep.version)
                    it.appendNode('scope', 'provided')
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```